# Trouble dividing indexes in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a for loop to divide every time in my array by 2, but I am not sure what my issue is. When I run the code, it does not divide the numbers by 2 and only outputs the initial array. Please help, and here is the code I've been working on.

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++ ) {
  myArray[i] / 2;
}
```

Comment: I meant by 2, not zero.

Comment: myArray[i]=myArray[i]/2;

Comment: var myArray = [];
    appendItem(myArray, randomNumber(1,10));
    appendItem(myArray, randomNumber(1,10));
    appendItem(myArray, randomNumber(1,10));
    appendItem(myArray, randomNumber(1,10));
    appendItem(myArray, randomNumber(1,10));
    appendItem(myArray, randomNumber(1,10));
 
    console.log("Original Array: " + myArray);

    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++ ) {
    myArray[i]) / 2;

    }

Comment: @Laurent S. thank you, that worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) the result of the division.

```
a = b      a simple assignment

a = a + b  \  basically the same
a += b     /  but this is shorter
```

```js
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    myArray[i] /= 2;
}

console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array= [20,10];
for(let i = 0; i<array.length; i++ ) {
    console.log(array[i]/2)
}
```